# How to PUBLISH specific replication agent using cURL commands?

Tags: java, curl, aem, aem-6

In programmatically, how to publish a particular replication agent using cURL commands?

I am activating the page using the below cURL command.

```
String[] command1 = { "curl", "--insecure", "-u", username + ":" + password, "-X", "POST", "-F", "path=" + pathForReplication, "-F", "cmd" + "=" + "activate", url };
```

My scenario was changed, Now I need to publish the particular replication agent only.

Comment: How would you define a 'replication agent'?

Comment: Currently, I am activating the page using cURL command.

Comment: what do you mean by replicating agent?

Comment: for publishing the content we need replication agents right, for suppose I am having two replication agents, I need to use only one replication agent action. How can I perform that one replication agent action using the cURL command??

Comment: It seems the replication command servlet (com.day.cq.replication.impl.servlets.CommandServlet)  looks only for 4 parameters: path, batch, cmd, version (=revision). So it is not possible with the out-of-the-box replication-command-servlet. I think you have to write your own (which is not complicated). At least the Replicator-Service supports an AgentFilter (via ReplicationOptions).

Comment: More likely, you will need a previous script/code to enable/disable specific agents. Once you activate a resource, the author instance will send that to all available (that is, enabled) replication agents.